# Handsontable: how to get instance by container?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I need to create a function that does some data updates and re-rendering to a rendered instance of handsontalbe (`var ht = new Handsontable(el,options)`). What I can easily get in my case is `el` (the element which is used as a container of the instance). Is it possible to get `ht` by only knowing `el`? Or I have to "remember" `ht` somewhere to access it later?

(I've tried `Handsontable(el)` and it creates a new table, it doesn't return an already created instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the handsontable object from the DOM Element from which it has been constructed. The handsontable instance is just a wrapper, which controls DOM Element for viewing, and that element does not have reference to its wrapper.

That means you indeed need to store your reference to `ht` somewhere, just like you would another variable.

If your problem is the scope, make the table a property of window object, and it will be accessible from everywhere in your page. This can be done simply using:

```
window.ht = new Handsontable(el,options)
```

However, if possible avoid making such global variables and keep it in the proper scope.

Comment: So there's no method like `Handsontable.getInstances(element)` to achieve this, right?

Answer (score 4):

If you use jQuery, you should be able to do so:

```
// Instead of creating a new Handsontable instance
// with the container element passed as an argument,
// you can simply call .handsontable method on a jQuery DOM object.
var $container = $("#example1");

$container.handsontable({
    data: getData(),
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
});

// This way, you can access Handsontable api methods by passing their names as an argument, e.g.:
var hotInstance = $("#example1").handsontable('getInstance');
```

Here is the documentation link: https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.13.0/demo-jquery.html

Answer (score 2):

When you create the Handsontable - add a reference to the div - in this example the `hot` property

```
function loadSheet() {
  var container = document.getElementById('example_table')
  container.hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    height: 'auto',
    data: [
      ['', 'Tesla', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Ford'],
      ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
      ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
      ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ]
  })
}
```

Then when you need to get back to it later

```
function onClickAddRowToSheet() {
  var container = document.getElementById('example_table')
  var data = container.hot.getData()
  data.push(['2022', 40, 16, 13, 14])
  container.hot.updateData(data)
}
```

Comment: Sounds sane, have you tested this? I mean, on the long run, not just in a quick test

Comment: Yep..works for me

Answer (score 1):

Each instance has a `rootElement` you can test it here https://jsfiddle.net/zhfLboym/ so for a

```
const container = document.querySelector('#example1');
const hot = new Handsontable(container, settings)
```

the `rootElement` will be `div#example1.hot.handsontable.htColumnHeaders` or just `rootElement.id` for `example1`.

But there is no API for altering data nor settings based on the element, it has to be the reference to the instance. So I would recommend preparing an object that holds element and instance and use it for a reference.