# get handsonTable data with jquery

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I am new to the Handsontable API and I'm trying to retrieve the handsonTable data I've declared before in another function ( initTable() ) but I cannot find the right method to apply. Here is my code :

```
<div class="importPpDiv">
        <div class="divTablePp" id="divTablePp">
        </div>
 </div>
<button id="addGeometry" > Add </button>
```

```
function initTable() {
        const container = document.querySelector('#divTablePp')
        const gpsDynamicTable = new Handsontable(container, {
          data: [
            ['', ''],
          ],
          rowHeaders: function(index) {
            return 'Point ' + (index + 1)
          },
          colHeaders: ['X', 'Y'],
          colWidths: [100, 100],
          rowHeights: 40,
          height: 'auto',
          fillHandle: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            autoInsertRow: true
          },
          licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation'
          })
}

$('#addGeometry').on('click', function() {
          var dynamicTableGps = $('#divTablePp').handsontable('getInstance')
          var data = dynamicTableGps.getData()
          console.log("Data of handstonTable : ", data)
})
```

Lines 23 say that my variable dynamicTableGps is undefined. Anyone knows how to get the handsonTable I've declared in line 3

I tried to retrieve a handsonTable data that I declared but I don't know what method to apply

Comment: It seems that you did not execute the initTable() that creates the instance of Handsontable so you get `undefined` (the instance is not yet created).

Comment: Thnks for your suggestion. I found the answer of my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498726/handsontable-how-to-get-instance-by-container